# Python parsing log file for IP address and Protocol

Tags: python, parsing, loops, hash

this is my first question asked here at stackoverflow and am really looking forward to being part of this community. I am new to program and python was the most recommended first program by many people.

**Anyways**. I have a log file which looks like this:

```
"No.","Time","Source","Destination","Protocol","Info"
"1","0.000000","120.107.103.180","172.16.112.50","TELNET","Telnet Data ..." 
"2","0.000426","172.16.112.50","172.16.113.168","TELNET","Telnet Data ..." 
"3","0.019849","172.16.113.168","172.16.112.50","TCP","21582 > telnet [ACK]" 
"4","0.530125","172.16.113.168","172.16.112.50","TELNET","Telnet Data ..." 
"5","0.530634","172.16.112.50","172.16.113.168","TELNET","Telnet Data ..."
```

And I wanted to parse the log file using Python to make it look like this as the result:

> **From IP    135.13.216.191   Protocol Count:
>                                    (IMF          1)
>                                    (SMTP         38)
>                                    (TCP         24) (Total:        63)**

I would really like some help on what path to take to tackle this problem should I use lists and loop through it or dictionaries/tuples?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Where did `135.13.216.191` come from?

Comment: That was just an example but it was from one the lines from the destination field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll want to read in the text file

```
# Open the file
file = open('log_file.csv')
# readlines() will return the data as a list of strings, one for each line
log_data = file.readlines()
# close the log file
file.close()
```

Set up a dictionary to hold your results

```
results = {}
```

Now iterate over your data, one line at a time, and record the protocol in the dictionary

```
for entry in log_data:
    entry_data = entry.split(',')
    # We are going to have a separate entry for each source ip
    # If we haven't already seen this ip, we need to make an entry for it
    if entry_data[2] not in results:
        results[entry_data[2]] = {'total':0}
    # Now check to see if we've seen the protocol for this ip before
    # If we haven't, add a new entry set to 0
    if entry_data[4] not in results[entry_data[2]]:
         results[entry_data[2]][entry_data[4]] = 0
    # Now we increment the count for this protocol
    results[entry_data[2]][entry_data[4]] += 1
    # And we increment the total count
    results[entry_data[2]]['total'] += 1
```

Once you've counted everything, just iterate over your counts and print out the results

```
for ip in results:
    # Here we're printing a string with placeholders. the {0}, {1} and {2} will be filled
    # in by the call to format
    print "from: IP {0} Protocol Count: {1})".format(
        ip,
        # And finally create the value for the protocol counts with another format call
        # The square braces with the for statement inside create a list with one entry
        # for each entry, in this case, one entry for each protocol
        # We use ' '.join to join each of the counts with a string
        ' '.join(["({0}: {1})".format(protocol, results[ip][protocol] for protocol in results[ip])]))
```

Comment: Thanks Skunkwaffle am really liking the simplicity of the code.

Comment: @JohnSmith: You'd be mad not to use the built-in [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) to parse your csv file

Comment: @DSM I think you're right, and considering my answer has no votes, and Eric's has 7, his should probably be the answer. If the OP will switch the accepted answer to Eric's, I'd be okay with deleting mine.

Answer (score 9):

You can parse the file using the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open('logfile.txt') as logfile:
     for row in csv.reader(logfile):
         no, time, source, dest, protocol, info = row
         # do stuff with these
```

I can't quite tell what you're asking, but I think you want:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

# A dictionary whose values are by default (a
# dictionary whose values are by default 0)
bySource = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: 0))

with open('logfile.txt') as logfile:
     for row in csv.DictReader(logfile):
         bySource[row["Source"]][row["Protocol"]] += 1

for source, protocols in bySource.iteritems():
    protocols['Total'] = sum(protocols.values())

    print "From IP %s Protocol Count: %s" % (
        source,
        ' '.join("(%s: %d)" % item for item in protocols.iteritems())
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So would I simply loop through the results from this and count the number of times each protocol appears for each IP address? Thanks

Comment: @JohnSmith: My code already does this - did you miss my update?

Comment: Thank you, just saw the update. Thanks alot Eric i really appreciate the help. Also would this be fine even if the file am using is like 1-2 GB in size?

Comment: Two suggestions, both minor.  First, you can use `int` instead of `lambda: 0`.  Second, you need to skip the header line, or better yet use `for line in csv.DictReader(logfile): bySource[line["Source"]][line["Protocol"]] += 1` which also means you don't have to hardcode the line order.

Comment: @DSM: _"int instead of lambda: 0"_ - I'm aware of this, but for a newcomer to python, it's more consistent with the `lambda: defaultdict...`. `csv.DictReader(logfile)` I did not know this - thanks!

Comment: @JohnSmith: Should be - it doesn't load it all into memory

Answer (score 1):

I would begin by first reading the file into a list:

```
contents = []
with open("file_path") as f:
    contents = f.readlines()
```

Then you can split each line into a list of it's own:

```
ips = [l[1:-1].split('","') for l in contents]
```

We can then map these into a dict:

```
sourceIps = {}
for ip in ips:
    try:
       sourceIps[ip[2]].append(ip)
    except:
       sourceIps[ip[2]] = [ip]
```

And finally print out the result:

```
for ip, stuff in sourceIps.iteritems():
   print "From {0} ... ".format(ip, ...)
```

Comment: P.S: This is intended mainly as an example of some programming constructs that can be used in python, rathher than the 'optimal' solution to this problem using python, as the OP seemed to be looking for introductory programming information.

Comment: Thanks alot. This helped with setting up the list but how would I count the number of unique protocols to each IP address? Also each IP address is repeated many times with different Protocols used.

Comment: Updated to add translation into a map